# JSCodeShift: How to wrap object properties inside another property

Tags: javascript, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift, codemod

I am new to jscodeshift and I'm using it to transform existing code, I have achieved almost everything but I am stuck at a part where I need to transform existing objects (there could be multiple objects in a file). I couldn't find a good example code online, I am able to get the properties but I don't know how to transform them, I've tried several approaches without any luck.

Input:

```
const apiConfig = {
    url,
    location,
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
       test: 'test'
    },
    spinnerConfig: {
       ...
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 const apiConfig = {
    apiRequestOptions: { 
       url,
       location,
       method: 'GET',
       params: {
         test: 'test'
       },
       spinnerConfig: {
         ...
      },
   },
}
```

Jscodeshift:

```
export const parser = 'tsx'
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  return root
          .find(j.ObjectExpression)
          .filter(x => x.parentPath.parentPath.value.id.name == 'apiConfig')
          .forEach((path) => {
             // For each object literal 
             path.value.properties.forEach((property) => {
               // go through each property
               if (property.type !== "ObjectProperty") return;
                 // transform the obj here
            })
          }).toSource();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I'm able to transformed it.

Updated Code:

```
export const parser = 'tsx'
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(file.source);

  return root
          .find(j.ObjectExpression)
          .filter(x => x.parentPath.parentPath.value.id.name == 'apiConfig')
          .forEach((path) => {
             const newObj = j.property(
                    'init',
                    j.identifier('apiRequestOptions'),
                    j.objectExpression([
                       ...path.value.properties // spread the properties
                     ])
                   );
             path.value.properties = [] // mutate original 
             path.value.properties.push(newObj) // add a new one
            })
          }).toSource();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it could be solved using a tool I'm working on [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout):

```js
export const match = () => ({
    'const apiConfig = __object': ({__object}, path) => {
        const [property] = __object.properties;
        return property.key.name !== 'apiRequestOptions';
    }
});

export const replace = () => ({
    'const apiConfig = __object': ({__object}, path) => {
        const {properties} = __object;
        
        __object.properties = [
            ObjectProperty(Identifier('apiRequestOptions'), ObjectExpression(properties))
        ]
        
        return path;
    }
});
```

You can check it out in [Putout Editor](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/64300ea826c5f12a561d275533c3d5aa/5d544164205ccc4e89bd7f5ac6e7ec829d53e8ea).

- `match` - preserves fixing only when `apiRequestOption` is missing;
- `__object` checks for `ObjectExpression` and `ObjectPattern` according to  [PutoutScript](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/blob/master/docs/putout-script.md)

Comment: Do you have a solution for that too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74581139/how-to-add-a-param-to-a-callexpression-with-jscodeshift ?

Comment: Sure https://stackoverflow.com/a/74604434/4536327